# Clang doesn't link dependencies of GTK3 and Webkit2GTK

Tags: c, clang, gtk3

I'm making a simple web browser using GTK3 and Webkit2GTK. When compiling the program, it doesn't have any error, but when I try to run it, I got this error:

```
$ ./a.out
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "./a.out": library "libGL.so" not found
```

I tried to compile the program with `-lGL`, but it throws another executable link error.

What did I doing wrong? This is my command:

```
clang main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 webkit2gtk-4.0`
```

Comment: `clang main.c \`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 webkit2gtk-4.0\` -lGL`? libGL.so is not part of either Gtk+3 or webkit2gtk, so you need to explicitly provide the library.

Comment: I know, but it will throw a executable link error if i don't include it